# "Unrecognized Field: http" in yaml when deploying dropwizard project to heroku

Tags: java, heroku, yaml, dropwizard

I've got a very simple dropwizard project (based on the [Dropwizard hello world](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html)) that I'd like to deploy to heroku.  For a reason I have not yet been able to determine, it fails to run after successfully building in heroku.  It runs fine locally; I only see this error on heroku:

heroku log:

```
2016-05-11T06:11:35.276279+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-05-11T06:11:35.276284+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-05-11T06:11:35.317873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-05-11T06:11:37.914144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.http.port=56125 -Ddw.http.adminPort=56125 -jar target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml`
2016-05-11T06:11:39.645193+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2016-05-11T06:11:39.648486+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2016-05-11T06:11:40.723314+00:00 app[web.1]: hello-world.yml has an error:
2016-05-11T06:11:40.723347+00:00 app[web.1]:   * Unrecognized field at: http
2016-05-11T06:11:40.723348+00:00 app[web.1]:     Did you mean?:
2016-05-11T06:11:40.723372+00:00 app[web.1]:       - metrics
2016-05-11T06:11:40.723373+00:00 app[web.1]:       - server
2016-05-11T06:11:40.723374+00:00 app[web.1]:       - logging
2016-05-11T06:11:40.723374+00:00 app[web.1]:       - defaultName
2016-05-11T06:11:40.723375+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-11T06:11:41.637830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-05-11T06:11:41.614715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

The thing is, as far as I can tell, my hello-world.yml doesn't have an "http" field....

```
defaultName: steve
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /
  #adminContextPath: /admin # If you plan to use an admin path, you'll need to also use non-root app path
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 8080
```

My Procfile, for good measure:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.http.port=$PORT -Ddw.http.adminPort=$PORT -jar target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml
```

The reason my yml file looks like it does is that I saw [this Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/QWsF22rRk1o) about the same error... unfortunately, the posted solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dropwizard merges any system properties with the prefix 'dw' into its configuration, so the error is actually referring to '`-Ddw.http.port=$PORT`' - change it to the following so it matches the structure of your configuration file.

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.server.connector.port=$PORT -jar target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml
```